# PHP file upload returns empty file type

Tags: php, html, image, upload

I have a very simple upload image which works on one page but returns empty file name in another page

```
   if (isset($_POST['upload_img'])) {
   $file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['img']['name'];
   $random_digit=rand(0000000,9999999999);
   $new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name.'.jpg';
   $path= "images/".$new_file_name;

  echo"$file_name"; 

  }
```

and this is the html form

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="img">
</div>

<p><a href="">Terms and conditions</a></p>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="upload_img">Upload    </button>

</form>
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: i dont see the opening `<form>` ?

Comment: I had it, it wasnt showing up here

Comment: And use `<input type="submit" name=...`

Comment: done that, still same, button is no different than input type="submit"

Comment: don't use `$HTTP_POST_FILES` as long as it's deprecated. Use `$_FILES` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$file_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
```

instead of

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['img']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

uploadpage.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
   $file_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
   $random_digit=rand(0000000,9999999999);
   $new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name.'.jpg';
   $path= "images/".$new_file_name;

  echo"$file_name"; 

  }

 ?>
```

index.php:

```
<form action="uploadpage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="img">
</div>

<p><a href="">Terms and conditions</a></p>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="upload_img">Upload    </button>
```